# Show that the magnitude of $\psi = Ae^{i \omega t}$ is A. Prove that $e^{i \alpha}e^{i \beta} = e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}$.

Tags: proof-verification, trigonometry, complex-numbers, physics, wave-equation

I am doing problem 2.44 from the textbook *Optics, 5th edition*, by Hecht:

> Working with exponentials directly, show that the magnitude of $\psi = Ae^{i \omega t}$ is A. Then rederive the same result using Euler's formula. Prove that $e^{i \alpha}e^{i \beta} = e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}$.

My work is as follows:

$$\begin{align} ||\psi|| &= ||Ae^{i \omega t}|| \\ &= ||A|| \cdot ||e^{i \omega t}|| \ \ \text{(Since $A \in \mathbb{R}$.)} \\ &= A \cdot ||e^{i \omega t}|| \ \ \text{(Since $A$ is the amplitude of the wave, which must be positive.)} \\ &= A(1) \ \ \text{(Since $|z| = |re^{i \omega t}| = r$, which in this case is just equal to 1.)} \\ &= A \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} ||\psi|| &= || A[ \cos(\omega t) + i \sin(\omega t)] || \\ &= || A || \cdot ||\cos(\omega t) + i \sin(\omega t) || \\ &= || A || \cdot \sqrt{\cos^2(\omega t) + \sin^2(\omega t)} \ \ \text{(By definition of the magnitude of a complex number.)} \\ &= || A || \\ &= A \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} e^{i \alpha} e^{i \beta} &= [\cos(\alpha) + i \sin(\alpha)][\cos(\beta) + i\sin(\beta)] \\ &= \cos(\alpha) \cos(\beta) + i \sin(\beta) \cos(\alpha) + i \cos(\beta) \sin(\alpha) - \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) \\ &= \cos(\alpha) \cos(\beta) - \sin(\alpha) \sin(\beta) + i[ \cos(\beta) \sin(\alpha) + \sin(\beta) \cos(\alpha) ] \\ &= \cos(\alpha + \beta) + i[\sin(\alpha + \beta)] \\ &= e^{i(\alpha + \beta)} \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} e^{i(\alpha + \beta)} &= \cos(\alpha + \beta) + i \sin(\alpha + \beta) \\ &= \cos(\alpha) \cos(\beta) - \sin(\alpha) \sin(\beta) + i[ \cos(\beta) \sin(\alpha) + \sin(\beta) \cos(\alpha) ] \\ &= \cos(\alpha) \cos(\beta) + i \sin(\beta) \cos(\alpha) + i \cos(\beta) \sin(\alpha) - \sin(\alpha) \sin(\beta) \\ &= [ \cos(\alpha) + i \sin(\alpha) ] [\cos(\beta) + i \sin(\beta) ] \\ &= e^{i \alpha} e^{i \beta} \end{align}$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please review my work for correctness.

Comment: This looks perfectly fine, but why do you prove the last statement twice?

Comment: Your solution is right. You don't need the last proof. You only have to proof it from both directions if a statement is given by "if and only if".

Comment: @LucasSmits Thanks for the review. Now that you mention it, I think I was thinking in terms of proving equivalence between statements in a proof (to prove that two statements are equivalent, we prove that each statement implies the other). You're right that it wasn't necessary here, since equality between two expressions isn't the same thing as proving equivalence between two statements.

Comment: @Samdney Indeed. Thanks for the review.